# How to save content on the page after navigating on it back

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a page with 4 TextBoxes. Each time pressing on the TextBox I use the `NavigationService` to navigate to the new page in order to make a comfortable input through Itembox. I use `NavigationContext` in order to send the selection from the Itembox. But each time navigating back to the first page, constructor of the page gets called and I see empty TextBoxes instead of filled ones.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actively navigate "back" to your main page using `NavigationService.Navigate()`? Don't do this, just use `NavigationService.GoBack()` or let the user use the Back button.

You can transfer the value via `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State`. Add this to your page where the user enters the value into the Itembox:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["name"] = "value";
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

This saves the value when the user goes back to the main page. And to your main page code add:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("name"))
        textBox1.Text = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["name"];
}
```

This tries to get the value and sets it to the `TextBox`.